# Memory leak in Spring library : SimpleMessageStore

Tags: memory-leaks, spring-integration

3 of the webservices that I am working on uses Springs, SimpleMessageStore for storing the messages. For some reason it is causing memory leak in production env and I am unable to reproduce it in the lower environments. I am new to spring integration and need help in understanding what might be causing this.

the spring config code looks like this:

```
<!--  MESSAGE STORES -->  
<bean id="monitoringHeaderRequestMsgStore" class="org.springframework.integration.store.SimpleMessageStore"/>
<bean id="gbqHeaderRequestMsgStore" class="org.springframework.integration.store.SimpleMessageStore"/>
<bean id="bondAgreementResponseMsgStore" class="org.springframework.integration.store.SimpleMessageStore"/>
<bean id="bondWIthRulesRequestMsgStore" class="org.springframework.integration.store.SimpleMessageStore"/>

<bean id="ProcessVariableMessageStores" class="com.aviva.uklife.investment.impl.ProcessVariableMessageStores">
    <property name="_monitoringHeaderRequestMsgStore" ref="monitoringHeaderRequestMsgStore"/>
    <property name="_gbqHeaderRequestMsgStore" ref="gbqHeaderRequestMsgStore"/>
    <property name="_bondWIthRulesRequestMsgStore" ref="bondWIthRulesRequestMsgStore"/>
    <property name="_bondAgreementResponseMsgStore" ref="bondAgreementResponseMsgStore"/>
</bean>

<!--  Retrieve stored MonitoringHeaderRequest -->
<int:transformer expression="headers.get('#{T(.....Constants).MONITORING_HEADER_REQUEST_CLAIM_CHECK_ID}')"/>
<int:claim-check-out message-store="monitoringHeaderRequestMsgStore" remove-message="false"/>
<!--  Store HeaderRequest -->
<int:gateway request-channel="header-req-store-channel"/>

<!--  PROCESS VARIABLES STORAGE IN STORE CHANNELS WITH KEY OR CLAIMCHECK ID -->

<int:chain input-channel="monitoring-header-req-store-channel">
    <int:claim-check-in message-store="monitoringHeaderRequestMsgStore"/>
    <int:header-enricher>
        <int:header name="#{T(....Constants).MONITORING_HEADER_REQUEST_CLAIM_CHECK_ID}" expression="payload"/>
    </int:header-enricher>
    <int:claim-check-out message-store="monitoringHeaderRequestMsgStore" remove-message="false"/>
</int:chain>
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, it isn't recommended to use `SimpleMessageStore` in the production environment. That's because of memory-leak, as you noticed. If you don't clear the `MessageStore` periodically.

Right, there are might be some cases, when you need to keep messages in the `MessageStore` for the long time. So consider to replace `SimpleMessageStore` with some [persistent](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/system-management-chapter.html#message-store) `MessageStore`.

From other side we need to have more info on the matter to provide better help.

Maybe you just have several aggregators and don't use `expire-groups-upon-completion = "true"`...

Comment: Thank you so much for the response Artem. There are no aggregators used. Also, the remove-message boolean attribute on the claim-check-out transformer is set to false in the spring config file and the MessageStores are being cleared programatically as against declaratively.
Could this be a reason for memory leak?

Comment: Well, share, please, your config around MSs and point out how you get deal with them.

Comment: From other side try to use only single `SimpleMessageStore` beanthroughout the app

Comment: Herez the config code :                                                      <!--  MESSAGE STORES -->
  <bean id="monitoringHeaderRequestMsgStore" class="org.springframework.integration.store.SimpleMessageStore"/>
  <bean id="gbqHeaderRequestMsgStore" class="org.springframework.integration.store.SimpleMessageStore"/>
  <bean id="bondAgreementResponseMsgStore" class="org.springframework.integration.store.SimpleMessageStore"/>
  <bean id="bondWIthRulesRequestMsgStore" class="org.springframework.integration.store.SimpleMessageStore"/>

Comment: <bean id="ProcessVariableMessageStores" class="com.aviva.uklife.investment.impl.ProcessVariableMessageStores">
  <property name="_monitoringHeaderRequestMsgStore" ref="monitoringHeaderRequestMsgStore"/>
  <property name="_gbqHeaderRequestMsgStore" ref="gbqHeaderRequestMsgStore"/>
  <property name="_bondWIthRulesRequestMsgStore" ref="bondWIthRulesRequestMsgStore"/>
  <property name="_bondAgreementResponseMsgStore" ref="bondAgreementResponseMsgStore"/>
 </bean>

Comment: <!--  Retrieve stored MonitoringHeaderRequest -->
 <int:transformer expression="headers.get('#{T(.....Constants).MONITORING_HEADER_REQUEST_CLAIM_CHECK_ID}')"/>
 <int:claim-check-out message-store="monitoringHeaderRequestMsgStore" remove-message="false"/>
  <!--  Store HeaderRequest -->
 <int:gateway request-channel="header-req-store-channel"/>

Comment: <!--  PROCESS VARIABLES STORAGE IN STORE CHANNELS WITH KEY OR CLAIMCHECK ID -->
  
  <int:chain input-channel="monitoring-header-req-store-channel">
  <int:claim-check-in message-store="monitoringHeaderRequestMsgStore"/>
  <int:header-enricher>
   <int:header name="#{T(....Constants).MONITORING_HEADER_REQUEST_CLAIM_CHECK_ID}" expression="payload"/>
  </int:header-enricher>
  <int:claim-check-out message-store="monitoringHeaderRequestMsgStore" remove-message="false"/>
 </int:chain>

Comment: @Kavi, it looks bad in the comment. You can edit your question and represent code snippet there with highlighting.

Comment: Yup.. have edited the Q and added the code snippet.. please help!!